# Infinite loop inside useEffect while trying to use Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, loops, use-effect

I'm building an app to write down values for electrical and gas meter : https://n3g.gitlab.io/react-conso-energie/

If you check the console, you'll see an infinite print of a console.log.

Here's the file where this magic happen :
https://gitlab.com/n3g/react-conso-energie/-/blob/br/V2/src/ListingExpansionPanels.js

I don't understand why my useEffet (line 19) is fired infinitely although I've add [dbRef] check at line 36..

In my imagination, it would be fired only if I add or remove things in my database ?

Thanks you if someone can take a look because I'm struggeling with this since few weeks. I do believe I'm over complicate things when I try to fecth data from my database..

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping `firebase.database().ref('2020')` with useRef hook like this:

```
const dbRef = useRef(firebase.database().ref('2020'));
```

And remove dbRef from useEffect deps array, change usage from `dbRef` to `dbRef.current`

Comment: Thanks, yes it works, but when I add or remove items, the display doesn't refresh now.

Comment: Your data comes from the firebase database, you pass the callback function to this method`dbRef.orderByChild('trueDate').once` where you set the state, but it is called once in useEffect, on the first component render, so for example when you call the `handleDelete` method you just update the data in database, in order to see the changes you have to call this function `dbRef.orderByChild('trueDate').once` again and update the state in its callback function.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. In fact it was my fault for the last part, I was retrieving data with .once instead of .on - Now I don't even have to re-execute something in order to get the data after delete or add items.